# regex grouping and stop after first tilde

Tags: regex

i have this text ***XX_YYY~foo~foo~foo*** and i want to group **XX** and **YYY** and skip rest. 
X and Y can be one or more.

i have tried `(.*)_(.*)~.*?` but not gready takes the last `~`.

this works `(.*)_(.*)(~.*)(~.*)(~.*)` but there might not be anything after the XX and YY.

Comment: `(.*)_(.*?)~` should do. not gready before the ~, not after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `.` can match any character, so it is not a good fit for strings that have some sort of delimiters (unless you are extracting subvalues that may contain these delimiters).

In your case, it seems that (*if you really have to use a regex*), you may rely on the `^` anchor and a couple of negated character classes:

```
^([^_~]+)_([^~]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP5jY9/1)

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `([^_~]+)` - Group 1 matching one or more chars other than `_` and `~`
- `_` - an underscore
- `([^~]+)` - Group 2 capturing 1 or more chars other than a tilde.

**However**, string splitting would be more natural if you have access to string methods in your environment.

If your pattern is used in a sort of a method that requires a full string match, add `.*` to the end of the above pattern (and if the string input can have line breaks, make sure the dotall mode is enabled).